# Subscripts and Superscripts in spinner items in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I have a spinner that its items add in Java code :

```
spinnerList = new ArrayList<String>();
spinnerList.add("NO2 - maximum 1-hour concentration");
spinnerList.add("CO - maximum 8-hour concentration");
spinnerList.add("O3 - maximum 8-hour concentration");
spinnerList.add("SO2 - maximum 1-hour concentration");
spinnerList.add("PM2.5  - maximum 24-hour concentration");
spinnerList.add("PM10 - maximum 24-hour concentration");

dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerList);
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
firstPageSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

I want to show the 2 after NO and others as subscript. With help of other questions I tried this code :

```
...
spinnerList.add(Html.fromHtml("NO<sub>2</sub>") + " - maximum 1-hour concentration");
...
```

but unfortunately spinner item just run like before! Is this the problem of Spinner? - because the new code I've tried exactly worked in TextViews.

*Edited Part :

I added my whole custom layout to question:

This is a part of MainActivity xml file that include Spinner:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/firstPageFirstLinear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_above="@+id/firstPageTextView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/first_text_view" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/firstPageSpinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:dropDownVerticalOffset="25dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        >
    </Spinner>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the custom_spinner_item.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvL"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="7dp"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my adapter class :

```
  public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<CharSequence> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner_item, parent, false);

        TextView tvL = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.tvL);

        tvL.setText(spinnerList.get(position));
        tvL.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }
}
```

This is the part of onCreate in MainActivity class :

```
ArrayList<CharSequence> spinnerList;
MyAdapter dataAdapter;

final Spinner firstPageSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.firstPageSpinner);

    spinnerList = new ArrayList<CharSequence>();
    spinnerList.add(Html.fromHtml("NO<sub>2</sub>") + "NO2 - maximum 1-hour concentration");
    spinnerList.add("CO - maximum 8-hour concentration");
    spinnerList.add("O3 - maximum 8-hour concentration");
    spinnerList.add("SO2 - maximum 1-hour concentration");
    spinnerList.add("PM2.5  - maximum 24-hour concentration");
    spinnerList.add("PM10 - maximum 24-hour concentration");

    dataAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_spinner_item, spinnerList);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.custom_spinner_item);
    firstPageSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

and it is running the spinner items like before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @CommonsWare helped me I just changed this part:

```
spinnerList.add(Html.fromHtml("NO<sub>2</sub>") + "NO2 - maximum 1-hour concentration");
```

to this :

```
spinnerList.add(Html.fromHtml("NO<sub>2</sub> - maximum 1-hour concentration"));
```

and it's exactly worked as you see in the picture :[image]

Answer (score 1):

> is this the problem of Spinner ?

It is at least in part a problem with your data model. `Html.fromHtml()` does not return a `String`. It returns a `Spanned` instance, which will contain the formatting. Because you are stuffing that `Spanned` into an `ArrayList<String>`, Android is calling `toString()` on the `Spanned`, eliminating the formatting.

Change your `ArrayList<String>` to `ArrayList<CharSequence>`, and change your `ArrayAdapter<String>` to `ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>`, and you may have better luck.

Comment: i tried this but unfortunately didn't work. the output in runtime is still NO2 ...

Comment: is there any other idea for succeed ?

Comment: @Fisher: If the text happens to also be appearing in all caps, you may need to use your own layout instead of `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item`. Otherwise, you must have some additional problem beyond the one I cited, and I cannot think of what it would be off the top of my head.

Comment: would you mind helping me to find an appropriate custom spinner that you mean ? because i made a custom spinner but again it is like before!

Comment: @Fisher: I agree with CommonsWare. You should define your own. please add your newly created layout to the question, may be it helps.

Comment: @CommonsWare: please help me. added my whole code. thank you.

Comment: @Fisher: Well, you are not using superscripts and subscripts in that code. Also, I just realized that in your `Html.fromHtml()` stuff, you were concatenating that with result with another `String` using `+`. Do not do that. Either put the whole text in the HTML, or [use `concat()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#concat%28java.lang.CharSequence...%29), as right now, that `+` creates a `String`, and so you lose your formatting.

Comment: @CommonsWare: i did like this : spinnerList.add(Html.fromHtml("NO<sub>2</sub> - maximum 1-hour concentration"));  and it is exactly working ! the problem was the thing you said. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for you but may be not just the best one.
You can simulate tags and behaviors you want in the custom layout you've created.

Let's consider that you put three TextView instead of that one in the xml file. Then set the font size of the first and last equal, and a smaller size for the middle item.

Or another one: replace the TextView with an LinearLayout and in the adapter fill it with needed TextViews. So you can now set an html code as the input and if you saw a sub, make an specual TextView for it.

We call the solutions like this "mast mal" or "tof mal" in our company and I am so intelligent to find these ones.

Comment: thank you. but the problem was about my concatination. I put whole my String in Html.fromHtml( "..."); and it solved.

Comment: I voted you up just for your "mast mal" way. dahaneto

Comment: @Fisher, thank you for your vote up. i wish you post your complete solution as a self answer. It will be helpful for others. Thanks in advance.